# I need a download of the Enterprise Development Reference Architecture

Tags: .net, architecture, soa, architectural-patterns

I'd like to get the assets that were part of the 
patterns & practices: Enterprise Development Reference Architecture: Releases: Home

The releases used to be on GotDot.net -  http://www.gotdotnet.com/workspaces/releases/viewuploads.aspx?id=9c29a963-594e-4e7a-9c45-576198df8058

I haven't found any resources on http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/ site.

Microsoft has a KB regarding this topic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/872836, but most of the links lead no-where.

The Retired patterns & Practices downloads don't seem to have it either, but maybe I'm missing it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921344.aspx

I'm kindof assuming it's known as the Web Service Software Factory, and can be downloaded here: http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/releases/view/9600, as the release called Web Service Software Factory v2 (deprecated), but would sure appreciate some validation on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still need the assets of EDRA (also known as ShadowFax)?  I have most (if not all) of the downloads that were available at the time for the framework (around 2005 - uses .NET 1.1), including source code and documentation.  We built an Enterprise Application Integration (EAI) solution based on that framework, and extended the messaging request/response endpoints to include IBM MQ and configurable database stored procedure adapters (Oracle or SQL Server).  I will monitor this post over the next two weeks or so to see whether you respond.

Comment: Please provide me your email Id and I will send them to you (Note:  I just put my email ID on my profile comments - you can get it there). I have rounded up the two reference guides - they zip to 7M. 1) EDRA (Architecture whitepaper) 489 pages 2) EDRI Global Bank Reference Implementation - 164 pages Do you need the source code too?

Comment: sent me the email files out of band. I plan to post these to codeplex in the near future.